# Unable to locate package ros-kinetic-desktop-full

Tags: ros-kinetic, debian

[image: Rosanswers logo]

$ apt-cache search ros-kinetic-ros-base
> *NOTHING*

```
 $ uname -a
Linux debian 3.16.0-10-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.70-1 (2019-07-22) x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list
deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu jessie main

$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    core-2.0-amd64:core-2.0-noarch:core-3.0-amd64:core-3.0-noarch:core-3.1-amd64:core-3.1-noarch:core-3.2-amd64:core-3.2-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch:security-4.0-amd64:security-4.0-noarch:security-4.1-amd64:security-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 8.11 (jessie)
Release:    8.11
Codename:   jessie

$ sudo apt-get update
Ign http://ftp.fr.debian.org jessie InRelease                                                                            
Ign http://download.opensuse.org  InRelease                         
Hit http://packages.ros.org jessie InRelease                        
Get:1 http://download.opensuse.org  Release.gpg [481 B]                                                                  
Hit http://packages.ros.org jessie/main amd64 Packages                                                                   
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates InRelease                                                   
Hit http://ftp.fr.debian.org jessie Release.gpg                                                
Hit http://download.opensuse.org  Release                                                      
Ign http://download.opensuse.org  Release                                                                             
Ign http://download.opensuse.org  Packages/DiffIndex                                                                  
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main Sources                                  
Hit http://ftp.fr.debian.org jessie Release                                                               
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/contrib Sources                                                            
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/non-free Sources                                                           
Hit http://ftp.fr.debian.org jessie/main Sources                                                                         
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages                                                        
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/contrib amd64 Packages                                                     
Hit http://ftp.fr.debian.org jessie/contrib Sources                                                                      
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/non-free amd64 Packages                                                    
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/contrib Translation-en                                                     
Hit http://ftp.fr.debian.org jessie/non-free Sources                                                                     
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main Translation-en                                                        
Ign http://packages.ros.org jessie/main Translation-en_IN                                                                
Ign http://packages.ros.org jessie/main Translation-en                                                                   
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/non-free Translation-en                                                    
Hit http://ftp.fr.debian.org jessie/main amd64 Packages                                                                  
Hit http://ftp.fr.debian.org jessie/contrib amd64 Packages                                                               
Hit http://download.opensuse.org  Packages                                                                               
Hit http://ftp.fr.debian.org jessie/non-free amd64 Packages                                                              
Ign http://download.opensuse.org  Translation-en_IN                                                                      
Ign http://download.opensuse.org  Translation-en                                                                         
Hit http://ftp.fr.debian.org jessie/contrib Translation-en                                                               
Hit http://ftp.fr.debian.org jessie/main Translation-en                                                                  
Hit http://ftp.fr.debian.org jessie/non-free Translation-en                                                              
Fetched 481 B in 19s (24 B/s)                                                                                            
Reading package lists... Done
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/329565/unable-to-locate-package-ros-kinetic-desktop-full/) by [ROS_ain't_workin](https://answers.ros.org/users/44377/ros_ain%27t_workin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2019-07-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ROS_ain't_workin](https://answers.ros.org/users/44377/ros_ain%27t_workin/) on 2019-07-29**:
Will ROS ever work on any OS?

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2019-07-29**:
Kinetic works on Ubuntu Xenial (16.04), Melodic works on Ubuntu Bionic (18.04), and any other [targeted platform](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html).

**Comment by [ROS_ain't_workin](https://answers.ros.org/users/44377/ros_ain%27t_workin/) on 2019-07-29**:
Bumblee isn't working on Ubuntu

**Comment by [ROS_ain't_workin](https://answers.ros.org/users/44377/ros_ain%27t_workin/) on 2019-07-29**:
Why does ROS only support buggy Ubuntu?
Do they want nobody to use it?

**Comment by [ROS_ain't_workin](https://answers.ros.org/users/44377/ros_ain%27t_workin/) on 2019-07-29**:
I had Arch derivative, but ROS doesn't get installed despite experimental support.
Docker installation works, but it doesn't launch UI inside gazebo. I have been troubleshooting from past 1-2 months.

Seems combination of Optimus/Ryzen + Ubuntu/Debian/Any Existing OS + ROS doesn't work at all.
Every single one of them keeps giving new Errors each time I troubleshoot the old one.

**Comment by [ROS_ain't_workin](https://answers.ros.org/users/44377/ros_ain%27t_workin/) on 2019-07-30**:
MAYBE ROS & UBUNTU BOTH LIKES AFFINITY OF BUGGY-NESS.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2019-07-30**:
Something does appear to be out of sync here. The kinetic install wiki indicates Debian Jesse support: http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Debian , but Jesse is not listed on the repository status page: http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_kinetic_default.html , and none of the ROS packages show up in the package index: http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/dists/jessie/main/binary-amd64/Packages .

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2019-07-30**:
It looks like build farm support for debian Jesse support was turned off here: https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/pull/18151

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have updated the Kinetic wiki to reflect the fact that the binary debs are no longer available: http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Debian . You may want to try a newer version of ROS on a newer version of Ubuntu or Debian. Hardware support for very recent graphics cards and CPUs tends to be much better in linux distributions that were created after the hardware was introduced.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2019-07-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0